# Background Image On Bootstrap Hero Unit

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background

Can you please help me to set a background image to a hero unit in Bootstrap because I am having issues with it, my code is as follows:

```
.hero-unit {
    background-image:url(../img/banner.jpg)
    padding: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 30px;
    webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
.hero-unit {
   background: url('../img/banner.jpg');
}
```